# Getting Bad credentials with InMemoryUserDetails in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, microservices, jwt, spring-security-rest

I am using spring boot oauth, while doing authorization I am not able to validate my credentials even if I used inMemory.

My authorization server:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Import(ServerWebSecurityConfig.class)
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    static final String CLIEN_ID = "ipro-client";
    static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "ipro-secret";
    static final String GRANT_TYPE = "password";
    static final String AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "authorization_code";
    static final String REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";
    static final String IMPLICIT = "implicit";
    static final String SCOPE_READ = "read";
    static final String SCOPE_WRITE = "write";
    static final String TRUST = "trust";
    static final int ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 1 * 60 * 60;
    static final int FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 6 * 60 * 60;
    static final String REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:8888/login";

    /*@Autowired
    @Qualifier("ibrdatasource")
    private DataSource dataSource;*/

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    /*
     * @Override public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
     * throws Exception { JdbcClientDetailsService jdbcClientDetailsService = new
     * JdbcClientDetailsService(dataSource);
     * clients.withClientDetails(jdbcClientDetailsService); }
     */

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {

        configurer.inMemory().withClient(CLIEN_ID).secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
            .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IMPLICIT)
            .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST).redirectUris(REDIRECT_URI)
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("123");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder userPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(4);
    }

}
```

And I am adding userdetails with inMemory data:

```java
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

    InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
    manager.createUser(User.withUsername("user").password("user").roles("USER").build());
    manager.createUser(User.withUsername("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN").build());
    return manager;

}
```

But I am not able to validate these details.
It's showing bad credentials. Please help me on this, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder userPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(4);
}

@Autowired
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
    manager.createUser(
        User.withUsername("user").password(this.passwordEncoder.encode("user")).roles("USER").build());
    manager.createUser(User.withUsername("admin").password(this.passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
        .roles("USER", "ADMIN").build());
    return manager;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because you're not encoding your password.

Use the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` when setting the password. Also, you'll have to tell the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` that you're authenticating in memory.

Create a class that extends from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, inject the bean of type `BCryptPasswordEncoder` and use it when defining the in memory authentication.

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password(this.passwordEncoder.encode("user")).roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("admin").password(this.passwordEncoder.encode("admin")).roles("USER", "ADMIN").and()
    }
}
```

Comment: I used password encoder now it is working fine thank you @Matheus cirillo.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, `SecurityConfiguration.java` is defined in same level pacakge as `SpringBootApplication.java`, since `@ComponentScan` default tells Spring to [scan current package and sub-packages](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning#component-scan-default), so `SecurityConfiguration`  is not scanned. after configure `@ComponentScan` [scan specific package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69272345/how-to-configure-componentscan-to-scan-specific-packages-and-get-single-classes) of `SecurityConfiguration`, issue is solved.