# How to configure @ComponentScan to scan specific packages and get single classes from another package?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How to configure component scanning to get beans from specifics packages and single classes from another? I'm trying that way, but TestClass1.class and TestClass2.class could not be found:

```
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {"com.example.package1", "com.example.package2"},
    includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = {com.example.package3.TestClass1.class, com.example.package3.TestClass2.class}))
```

Comment: I found pretty clear solution - define classes in `basePackageClasses` property.

    @ComponentScan(
        basePackages = {"com.example.package1", "com.example.package2"},
        basePackageClasses = {com.example.package3.TestClass1.class, com.example.package3.TestClass2.class})

Comment: I assume TestClass1 and TestClass2 do not have dependencies that also need to be included in the component scan?

Answer (score 2):

The attribute `basePackageClasses` does not work as you think. It does not scan only the configured classes, it scans the complete package of each class.

Which means that:

```java
@ComponentScan( basePackages = {"com.example.package1", "com.example.package2"}, 
basePackageClasses = {com.example.package3.TestClass1.class, com.example.package3.TestClass2.class})
```

is exactly the same as:

```java
@ComponentScan( basePackages = {"com.example.package1", "com.example.package2", "com.example.package2"} )
```

I would say that the simplest and cleanest way to do this is to use @Bean to define each bean:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.package1", "com.example.package2"})
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public TestClass1 testClass1() {
        // object creation
    }

    @Bean
    public TestClass2 testClass2() {
        // object creation
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to know how `basePackageClasses` works. In `@Bean` approach there is one disadvantage - need to create all beans manually, also dependencies.

Comment: That is in fact true. You would need to create `TestClass1` and `TestClass2` as depicted in my answer. If their dependencies are in packages "com.example.package1" or "com.example.package2", then you don't need to create them manually. I've edited my answer and added `@ComponentScan`.